# Would a "comment" have an implied brevity to it?

Tags: meaning

I always thought that a *comment* would be, in comparison to other kind of response, such as an answer, something brief. However, it doesn't seems like [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comment) says anything about it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: BTW, it sounds odd to describe the brevity of a comment to be "induced," unless you mean someone was persuaded or influenced into shortening it. You may be looking for the word *implied*.

Comment: Good point! On a side note, the difference between _induce_ and _imply_ may be a good theme for a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of a comment, when the meaning as "a remark expressing anopinion or reaction," is to be brief. That's why Stackexchange sites, for example, allow you a mere 600 characters to write one.

A *commentary* can be longer, even the length of a bible. *Comment* can carry the meaning of *commentary*, but that is an archaic usage.